# PyQt5: How to switch to a different page in stacked widget upon button click?

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5

The program below is pretty simple. It has a stacked widget with two pages. The first page has a push button that tells the user to click. The second page has text.

**I would like to have the program, upon clicking of the button in the first page, to go to the second page.** I tried watching YouTube tutorials that show how to do this, but many of them were unnecessary complicated, and they always resorted to creating a .py file and calling the .ui file from it, which is an extra step that I didn't have to go through with Tkinter.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.stackedWidget = QtWidgets.QStackedWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.stackedWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 0, 781, 571))
        self.stackedWidget.setObjectName("stackedWidget")
        self.PageOne = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.PageOne.setObjectName("PageOne")
        self.ClickMe = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.PageOne)
        self.ClickMe.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(340, 270, 75, 23))
        self.ClickMe.setObjectName("ClickMe")
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.PageOne)
        self.PageTwo = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.PageTwo.setObjectName("PageTwo")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.PageTwo)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(360, 280, 47, 13))
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.stackedWidget.addWidget(self.PageTwo)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.ClickMe.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Click me!"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Hello!"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: That extra step is not only important, but also almost mandatory. I know you feel that it's an annoying and unnecessary step, but **anybody** who thought that at first then realized they were wrong. Read how to properly use UI files in the official guidelines about [using Designer](//www.riverbankcomputing.com/static/Docs/PyQt5/designer.html), and be aware that trying to ignore these warnings (including the one you removed at the top of your script above) almost always results in well known problems that could be avoided if the suggestion was followed.

Comment: That said, it seems that you don't know what Qt [signals and slots](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/signalsandslots.html) are and how they work, so I suggest you to do a little research on pyqt tutorials (like [this](//zetcode.com/gui/pyqt5/) - avoid Youtube, they are often awful and suggest terrible practices), and then always read the documentation of the classes you're using (specifically the `currentIndex` property and `currentWidget()` functions of [QStackedWidget](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstackedwidget.html)).

Comment: Thank you so much for this wealth of information. I will be spending this weekend reading through the documentation, esp. about signals and slots, and learning more about the functions of Stacked Widget. I really appreciate your assistance!